# Chrome (Android) Keyboard carries word over to next input on js focus change

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

I have two inputs, when the first recieves an enter keyup, it focuses to the next one (see the script tag). On Chrome (49) on Android (6.0.1), when you press the -> button on the right-bottom of the keyboard (standard keyboard), it keeps the last word typed in the keyboard and carries it over to the new input.

Is there a way to prevent this or get a similar effect without that behaviour?

```
<input type="text" id="first-input"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<script>
 var first = document.getElementById('first-input');
 first.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    first.nextElementSibling.focus();
  }
}
```

Running example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jmn0pze7/1/

Comment: I'm coming up with the same problem. Did find a solution to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue on this question: [Android Chrome input onkeydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382539/android-chrome-input-onkeydown)

Clear the text on input focus

`$('input').val('');`